# Numpy math on each dimension without for loops

Tags: python, numpy

If I have a numpy array shaped (q,p), how can I perform math on each dimension without for loops?

For example, if my data are **q** and **p** and I pre-allocate a numpy array `x` of these dimensions:

```
q = [628, 314, 209]
p = [-33.2069, -411.137, -801.183, 52.92495]
x = np.zeros([len(q), len(p)], dtype=float)
print(x)
```

[image]

I can do a double for-loop to perform math on each dimension:

```
for ii in range(len(q)):
    for jj in range(len(p)):
        x[ii,jj] = p[jj] / np.square(q[ii])
print(x)
```

[image]

Can I achieve the same result without the loops?

Using Python 3.8.3

Comment: `p/np.sqrt(q)[:,None]`

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj, I will accept this as the answer if you post

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this as follows:

```py
import numpy as np

q = np.array([628, 314, 209])
p = np.array([-33.2069, -411.137, -801.183, 52.92495])

x = p / (q * q)[:, None]
print(x)
```

Output:

```py
[[-8.41994097e-05 -1.04247890e-03 -2.03147947e-03  1.34196494e-04]
 [-3.36797639e-04 -4.16991562e-03 -8.12591789e-03  5.36785975e-04]
 [-7.60213823e-04 -9.41226162e-03 -1.83416817e-02  1.21162405e-03]]
```